# Please select a certificate to authenticate yourself to

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams

Got this pop up message this morning on my computer:

Please select a certificate to authenticate yourself to

us-prod-asyncgw.teams.microsoft.com:443

-George Bennitt

-George Bennitt

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Microsoft has confirmed this issue. Check out this reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/MicrosoftTeams/comments/nwozrs/select_a_certificate_message/